# How Can I Speed Up This PHP Function?

Tags: php, string, function, loops, contains

I am making a php filter for my webpage that checks through an array, read in through a file, to see if several user input fields (name, description, etc.) contain any of the words in the array. I tried using the "strpos" function built into php but for whatever reason, it only detected the word if the word was the last thing in the string, ie if I were checking for the word "cat" it would detect it if it were checking "this is a cat" and "scat" but not if it were checking "cats" or "cat toy" or even just "cat " with a space after it. To be clear, I did check to see if the strpos function was not equal to false (strpos(...)!==false). So I made my own function that breaks the string up into every possible substring and checks each one to see if it equals any of the words in the array. Is there a faster way I could do this, or a way that I could speed up the execution of this code? Here is the code:

```
function arrayContains($string, array $array){
$string = strtolower($string);
$len=strlen($string);
 foreach($array as $check){
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        for($j=1; $j<=$len-$i; $j++){
            $sub=substr($string,$i,$j);
            if($sub==$check)
                return true;
        }
}
}
return false;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you could go the other way around and use `in_array()`

Comment: I just tried that and it is exponentially faster. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the strpos problem? I have a feeling that you don't differentiate between the function returning 0 and a boolean false. If you search for "cat" in "cats" or "cats " with a space it will return 0 because countable sets begin at position zero, not 1. If you're just doing " if (strpos()) { condition true }" the 0 is cast to false, so it wouldn't work. You need strict equality check, i.e. "if strpos(...) !== false..."

Comment: @carsond2704 - if you've found a solution, you can add it as an answer to your own question

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov my if statement said "if (strpos(...)!==false)"

Comment: Strange. In any case the array solution should be good enough :) Also, utilizing a database instead of reading from a file every time will probably net you some more speed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may have been misusing [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php); either putting arguments in the wrong order, or not checking for a true boolean result. This should work:

```
function foundInArray($string, $array){
    $string = strtolower($string);
    foreach($array as $check){
        if (strpos($string, strtolower($check)) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit to add results:

```
php > $array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
php > $string = "Cheese is a food I like";
php > var_dump(foundInArray($string, $array));
bool(true)
php > $string = "Cheese is a thing I like";
php > var_dump(foundInArray($string, $array));
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer, suggested by @developerwjk, helped solve my issue. I'm still open to more suggestions though if there are any.
    `function arrayContains($string, array $array){
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $len=strlen($string);
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=$len-$i; $j++){
    $sub=substr($string,$i,$j);
    if(in_array($sub, $array))
    return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
    }`